# Notify all clients after a fixed time from first RMI call to server

Tags: java, rmi

I want the server to notify multiple clients using callback after a fixed time from the first RMI call made to server.

ie Server will wait for fixed time , so that multiple client can join

```
//server code
void connect (callback) {

thread.sleep(time)
callback.notify()

}
```

But what happens is that all clients does not get the callback at same time . Variations depends on time of making the rmi call to server .
How to do i make sure that all clients get notification at the same time.

I m new to RMI and trying to implement a client- server mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Either you are going to call them back one by one, which already defeats simultaneity, or you call them in parallel, in which case you still have no control over thread execution, and in both cases you also have no control over how packets get sent to the network.

The problem here is the requirement itself, not how to implement it. Why should there be a fixed time after the first call? How can you know all the possible clients are connected within that fixed time? Why do the clients all need to get the notifcation at the same time? Why do you need the callback at all? Callbacks in RMI are often a sign of poor design, and callbacks of any kind are viewed with great suspicion by network administrators, for security reasons.

You don't need callbacks for a general client-server mechanism. RMI already is a client-server mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Bare in mind it has been quite some time since I've used RMI, 
and I agree with the other answer saying this is a problematic requirement. 
However, if this requirement is a must, 
 I would try to implement something like I'm about to suggested, 
 hoping I understand correctly that problem is that connect is invoked per each sever thread that serves an RMI call. 
I would suggest the following - 
Implement a shared data structures between the RMI server threads (i.e - those who run the call to "connect" method). 
.
The shared data structure can be a concurrent map of java.util.Date (or Long representing miliseconds) to a list of callbacks. 
The code of connect will perform the following pseudo code:

a. Check if there is an entry for the date object you would like to notify the callbacks for. 
 If there is no such entry, create it and put in the map and set "true" to newEntry flag 
b. Add the callback on the list. 
c. If "newEntryFlag" is  set, use [ScheduledThredPoolExectuor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) in order to schedule a task that will be invoked when the time of the date object is reached. 
d. When the time of the task has reached - the run method of the task will get the callback list from the shared map, and for each one of the callbacks invoke the notify method. 
Of course , you will need to handle synchronization properly here, I'm sure you can manage that.

Comment: You need to explain how that will achieve simultaneity. Not that it's possible.